# Using angular services in Web Worker

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, setinterval, web-worker

I have `factory` where I want to use `Web Worker` for angularJs ([lib from here](http://mattslocum.github.io/ng-webworker/))

```
var appServices= angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource', 'ngWebworker']);

appServices.factory('CurrentUserData', [
    'apiPath', '$resource', '$rootScope', 'Auth','Webworker',
    function (apiPath, $resource, $rootScope, Auth, Webworker) {
        var requests = $resource(apiPath + "/Requests", {});
        var pendingRequests = $resource(apiPath + "/RequestRecipient/Pending", {});

        var requestResources = [];
        var pendingRequestResources = [];

        var updateResources = function(resource, newResource) {
            if (angular.isArray(resource)) {
                resource.length = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < newResource.length; ++i) {
                    resource.push(newResource[i]);
                }
            } else {
                for (var key in resource) {
                    delete resource[key];
                }
                for (var key in newResource) {
                    resource[key] = newResource[key];
                }
            }
        };

        var fetchResources = function(){
            user = Auth.getCurrentUser();
            if(!user){
                return;
            }
            requests.query(function (requestResponse) {
                updateResources(requestResources, requestResponse);
            });
            pendingRequests.query(function (requestResponse) {
                updateResources(pendingRequestResources, requestResponse);
            });
        };


        fetchResources();
        setInterval(fetchResources, 120000); // Here I want to use Worker, which can Update requestResources and pendingRequestResources in "new thread"

        return {
            'requests': function() {
                return requestResources;
            },
            'pendingRequests': function() {
                return pendingRequestResources;
        }
}
```

I've tried to use web worker in next way :

```
    fetchResources();//init arrays

    if (window.Worker) { // Check if Browser supports the Worker api.
        var myWorker = Webworker.create(setInterval);
        myWorker.run(fetchResources, 120000).then(function(result) {
            console.log("done");
        });
    } else {

        setInterval(fetchResources, 120000);
    }
```

on start init my arrays and then in web-worker update them every 120000ms, but I get error:

> angular.js:11655 Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': An object could not be cloned.

So I think it's problem of my custon services, that I am using in function, which is passed into web-worker.

Comment: The problem is that you pass a function instead of data. `setInterval` as web worker makes no sense, it should be called inside the worker.

Comment: Where is `postMessage` called? In all the code you posted I don't see any `postMessage` method...

Comment: @Wilt, please check "documentation" of library that I use http://mattslocum.github.io/ng-webworker/ I think I did everything that is described in docs.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you pass in postMessage is invalid -- most likely passing a function? The worker is in a separate execution scope altogether, you cannot pass it any references to the DOM, local variables, scopes, etc.